# Is there an efficient way to import binary data from mysql database to Postgresql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, blob, bytea

I can use mysqldump and psql to import common data into the postgresql database. However, binary data is blob in mysql and bytea in postgresql. Import cannot be done using mysqldump and psql tools.

Comment: [How to migrate large blob table from mysql to postgresql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4211/how-to-migrate-large-blob-table-from-mysql-to-postgresql),  [pgloader](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/mysql.html),  [mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw).

Comment: https://ora2pg.darold.net/